# Using string splicing to provide a URL from an email?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that takes a user's email and prints the URL that it is associated with. So far, I have this:

```
def email_intake():
    '''Takes email input from the user'''
    email = input('Enter your email: ')
    if email.find('@'):
        return(email)

    else:
        print('Please enter a valid email address')
        email = input('Enter your email: ')



def find_domain(email):
    '''Figures out domain name associated with email provided by the user'''
    domain = email.split('@')[1]
    return (domain)




def url_printer(domain):
    '''prints URL associated with the email provided by the user'''
    print('The domain of this email address is http//:www. ', domain)


def main():
    email = email_intake
    domain = find_domain(email)
    url_printer(domain)


main()
```

I'm aware that i have to do some sort of string splicing to figure out my second function, but I am not sure where to go from here. I was wondering if there was some way I could gather the info from the @ character to the . if that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by URL ? if you are talking about the domain name of the email, which typically be after the '@' till the end

Your find_url method may look like this.

```
def find_url(email):
    return email.split('@')[1]
```

P.S: assuming that you already verified the validity of the email in your previous email_intake method.

Comment: Yes, I meant the domain name. I keep getting an error that says "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'split"